# Using Rules to block system email or prevent from sending?

Tags: rules

I have a unique use case. I am currently using mailcontrol module to disabled the sending of emails when news users are created. However I got to thinking about this, and I was wondering if there is a way to create a Rule to prevent the email from sending so I wouldn't have to use the mailcontrol module.

Comment: Please include drupal version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a custom module and lines in the setting.php?

Here is a [simple tutorial](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/preventing-emails-being-sent-drupal-7-development-environment) showing how `$message['send'] = FALSE;` can stop it. Of course, you can also use if statments to add conditions.

Note: The developer does mention that you shouldn't use it on production...